# Maintain view layout state after switching views

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sails.js, ejs

I've a collapsing sidebar in my layout view, and I added it to the layout as partial.

Let's say this is my sidebar menu:
- Students 
--- Create New
--- Edit
- Teacher 
--- Create New
--- Edit

(you can find the menu here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/accordion-list-group-menu , but this is not important).

The problem is, **when I access a link to a new page, the sidebar is back to the initial state, and the collapsed item isn't maintained, is there any way to solve this?**

For example:
Let's assume that the initial state is 'Student' is open and 'Teacher' collapsed.
1) I click Teacher, the Student collapses and Teacher opens.
2) If I go to New Teacher, that uses the same layout, the page opens with the initial state.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <%- partial('partials/sidebar.ejs') %>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <%- body %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, the menu snippet you linked to is *very* important to your question, as it is mainly a front-end issue.

Comment: So in order to solve this, the only way to do that is using Single-Page-Application? is there anyway to pass parameters to partials?